# Transfering Castle treasure to overburdened storage

Tags: clash-of-clans

I wanted to know, if my gold storages are almost full, then if I transfer my Castle treasury i.e. war loots to my storage. So at this point when I am transferring the gold and elixir, I have more gold than the storage can hold. So will the extra loot stay in the castle or will it be wasted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I waited long to make space in my gold storage. Then when transfered the extra elixir and dark elixir was still there in my castle. I found 0 gold, 22k elixir and 4 dark elixir in my castle after I transfered resources.

Comment: You can select your own answer as the correct answer. Please do that, as it is very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you transfer your loot from CC to your storage and there is an excess (storage is full already), the remaining gold, elixir or DE will be retained in the CC.

Answer (score 0):

The amount that couldn't be stored in your deposits will be kept in the clan castle. If you doesn't have room at all, in any storage, a red message will appear saying that your deposits are full.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to, keep the castle loot. The castle loot can be taken by raids, but only if the raider completely destroys the CC. If you are not active, then it will be wasted, because multiple people will raid you and take the gold/elixor/dark elixor.

Comment: Not sure if you understood what I asked about but thanks anyway.

Comment: What I would really suggest, is that the spend some of it, and then collect it because less loot is looted from storages.